# parsing string that uses xml like tags in a fast way

Tags: python, xml, string, python-3.x, parsing

i have a file that contains data in this format look like XML without the root tag

```
<Item>
     <ItemNumber>123</ItemNumber>
        <ItemData>
           very cool item
        </itemData>
        <ItemData>
         more informaion about this item
        </ItemData>
</Item>
<Item>
     <ItemNumber>123</ItemNumber>
        <ItemData>
           very cool item
        </itemData>
        <ItemData>
         more informaion about this item
        </ItemData>
</Item>
```

i have alot of files in this format(1800+ each file 1M-5M), and i need to parse them
In a way that would allow me to access the data between tags and 
optional data in the tags in a fast way.
i try to use beautifulSoup but i'ts not very efficient, 
tried also lxml but because i don't have a root tags i'ts make me lots of errors and i cant change the files

need to use python3

Answer (score 0):

using `fromstring` function from `lxml.html` as [described in example here](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#examples),

```
with open("d:/b.xml") as f:
    read_xml = fromstring(f.read())
    for tag in read_xml:
        print(tag.text_content().strip())
```

gives you,

```
123

           very cool item


         more informaion about this item
123

           very cool item


         more informaion about this item
```

Comment: the file has no .xml suffix so he cant open the file

Comment: just change the suffix in the code then, it will still work

Comment: i try this like you said and getting this : error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'b.xml'

Comment: where is you file? you need to provide correct path to your file in the code, not just copy paste my code

Comment: the file are not XML file they written in a tags like XML just witout root tag

Comment: my file is in the project folder

Comment: it doesn't matter if its a xml file, just replace `d:/b.xml` with the path to your file

Comment: still the same outcome.

Comment: understand the basic of python before asking question and attempt something.

Comment: the location of the file is inside the project so the full path don't matter it still try to open it with file name b.xml that dosent exist but b is

Comment: what is the name of the file in project folder? and what is the extension? the code couldn't file the file which means you are providing incorrect name

Comment: of course, already solve this with beautiful soup but the Performence are poor

Comment: there is not extension for the file i'ts a file from the type "file" (by the file properties)

Comment: if i allowed to do so i't will be great. but i cant change the file i have 1800+ file just like this and the format of the file is not exactly XML so if i do so it will show me error like this: lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 183, column 1

Comment: this should work for any file not just xml as long as file has tags. The reason of your error is your are not providing correct path to the file

Comment: i write your suggested code with the path "C:\\Users\myUser\PycharmProjects\SE\\b.xml"